# GlassFish 3.1 problem with /faces/*

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

I read that a facelet can be accessed, with GF 3.1, directly by:

1. http://localhost:8080/myapp/page.faces;
2. http://localhost:8080/myapp/page.jsf;
3. http://localhost:8080/myapp/faces/page.xhtml.

because that mapping is made automatically by the server.

However the last mapping doesn't work. I have the following error: `The requested resource () is not available.`

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: where did you read it , link please

Comment: On the book Core JavaServer Faces Third Edition ""NOTE: Some application servers (including GlassFish) automatically provide a servlet mapping for the /faces/*, *.faces, and *.jsf patterns"

Comment: Also on the book: Packtpub Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3 
Application Server: ""In traditional Java web applications, we define URL patterns to be processed by a specific servlet. Specifically for JSF, the suffixes .jsf or .faces were commonly 
used. Another commonly used URL mapping for JSF was the /faces prefix. By default, GlassFish automatically adds all three of these mappings to the faces servlet""

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE**: Some application servers
>   (including GlassFish) automatically
>   provide a servlet mapping for the
>   /faces/*, *.faces, and *.jsf patterns

It doesn't say it maps to `.xhtml` and so the result.

Comment: No, that mapping called as prefix, means that every file I write after /faces/ is processed. So when I write /faces/page.xhtml the server (the FaceServlet controller) should strip off /faces and point to page.xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that JSF support is aded to your web project. 
That was the issue for me.

In Eclipse IDE:

1. Right click Your project -> Properties
2. Select: Project Facets and confirm JavaServer Faces is checked.
3. If not check it and in my case it needed further configuration but I think everyone can figure it from there on